# Що замовити: каву чи кофе?

Tags: вибір-слова

Зустріла в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44584) *кофе*, як синонім до кава:

> КО́ФЕ, невідм., с., розм. Те саме, що [ка́ва 1](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39821&page=1259)
>
> *Пішла [Марта Кирилівна] в пекарню, заглянула в каструлі, навіщось вилаяла куховарку, понюхала кофе і чогось причепилася до Марусі* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *Марфа Галактіонівна допиває свою склянку кофе, допомагає Явдосі поставити посуд в буфет і нарешті сідає проти вікна (М. Хвильовий); Вона справно пила щоранку кофе з сухариками* (О. Донченко).

В ґуґлпошуку на запит *кофе* більшість результатів російськомовні. Але в прикладах зі словника наведені речення українських письменників, отже це слово справді використовувалось в українській мові. Чи на даний момент доцільно вживати *кофе* в українській мові?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обидва слова, очевидно, иншомовного походження. Згаданий запитачкою словник вже вказує на *розмовність* слова *кофе*.

Також корпуси чи іменки вказують на велику і схожу ріжницю вживу:

> Лайпціґ: [кава](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014) 10,032 — [кофе](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5) 280
>   Парасоль: [кава](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0&corpname=grac&corpus-search-form=true) 10,245 — [кофе](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5&corpname=grac&corpus-search-form=true) 200
>   Горох: [кава](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) 14754 — [кофе](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5) 213

Окрім цього:

- *[кава](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0)* відмінюється;
- *[ф](/a/2907/585)* — не питомий звук, тому можна стрітити навіть *[кохве](//google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B5"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off)*  <sup>[л](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B5) [п](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B5&corpname=grac&corpus-search-form=true)</sup>, *[кагве](//google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B5"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off)* <sup>[л](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B5) [п](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B5&corpname=grac&corpus-search-form=true)</sup>…
- инші складні слова на основі слова *кава* теж вживаніші, наприклад — *[кавʼярня](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F)*.

---

Стаття [Лідії Гнатюк](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:riwnhOg0OsoJ:philology.knu.ua/node/1345) — [Кава: історія слова в історії народів](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/110235/29-Gnatyuk.pdf)

> <sup>Частина</sup>
>
> …
>
> Проте в ЕСУМ не зафіксовано ще одного варіанта, який
>   був відомий староукраїнській літературній мові першої третини 18 ст. — *кагве*, що відтворює звучання цього слова турецькою мовою і безпосередньо пов’язаний, на нашу думку, з історією входження реалії в життя українців. Так, у щоденнику [Якова Марковича](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) від 1 березня 1725 р. натрапляємо на такий запис:
>
> > Панъ Скоропадскій и Минѣцкій були рано, и первой, *кагве* напившись, отехалъ (Дневникъ генеральнаго подскарбія Якова Марковича (1717‑1767). — К., 1893‑1897. — Ч. 1. — С. 207).
>
> Ось запис від 11 березня 1725 р.:
>
> > Покупки Демяновой осмотрувалемъ, между которою и *кагве* окъ 5, на якую розійшлося денегъ 98 зол. и 7 шаг., зъ даннихъ ему 100 зол. Начали *кагве* — и кубочокъ зсмажили (Там само. — С. 211)
>
> та від 17 березня цього ж року:
>
> > У князя рано былисмо и *кагве* напившись пришлисмо до церкви (Там само. — С. 214).
>
> Мабуть, пиття кави було певною подією для автора, чимось іще дуже новим і незвичним для того часу, бо в його щоденнику ніколи не згадується, скажімо, що він їв. Козацька старшина пила каву й під час походу, про що свідчать записи від 16 червня 1725 р.:
>
> > В день сидѣли в нас Борковскій и Томара и *кагве* напившись,
> >     отойшли (Там само. — С. 251);
>
> від 17 червня 1725 р.:
>
> > …пріехавши до табору, чай у Борковского и *кагве* у Лизогуба пилисмо (Там само. — С. 252).
>
> Каву можна було купити на ярмарку, що підтверджує запис від 7 вересня 1729 р.:
>
> > Господар повернулся з ярмарку кролевецкого, где купил око *кагве* (Дневникъ 
> >     З історії культури і писемності 175 генеральнаго подскарбія Якова Марковича (1717‑1767). — К.,
> >     1893‑1897. — Ч. 2. — С. 319).
>
> …

Comment: Припиніть, будь ласка, ліпити `и` на початку слів і вигадувати свої варіанти слів. Прошу Вас.

Comment: @BohdanKuts ніхто нічого не вигадує. https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/111.html проект правопису 99 року, як власне і в харківському (скрипниківка). Яким правописом послуговуватися людині - її особиста справа.

Comment: @ovnia, AFAIK, у харківському не було «и-» на початку слів (а було: «інший», «іноді» тощо). «И-» на початку слів — це спроба реанімувати ще старіший правопис. Але так, Ви праві, у проекті 99 і деяких дохарківських правописах це було.

Comment: @ovnia, я про те чи це хіба за діючим правописом? Якщо це з власного бажання, то так можна і до староруської вернутися. Окрім того, я не заперечую права на вибір яким правописом послуговуватися, але не на таких ресурсах де інформація поширюється поміж тисячами користувачів.